# How to make this painting look more realistic?

Tags: painting

I am no artist. But I spotted a paint by numbers kit which looked pretty cool at my grans, the image on the box was really nice, anyway as expected once it was "finished" it looked nothing like the box, I'm wondering if anyone knows what to do to make it look more realistic[image: Complete Image]

[image: Image on the box, what I'm aiming to transform it into...]

Comment: It looks like you need more detail...

Comment: Go in with a finer brush and add the hair.

Comment: Brand of the painting matters! Paint works by Dimensions (yes, the embroidery/craft people, one and the same) look VERY much like the box. So does PLAID. In my experience, I have never seen a Royal and Lang....something that turned out well. They put MUCH more detail on the box, do NOT put it in the drawing and you can't even top paint to fix it! Exception: The children's ones with little detail may do well.

Answer (score 2):

Paint-by-numbers, by design, is a low resolution drawing.

The painting on the box is a high resolution drawing.

This is called 'marketing' (Making something look better than reality) :)

Comment: I dont know why this got downvoted

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, it makes a snarky comment instead... so should be a comment.

Comment: @rebusB you are correct, it doesn't answer the question directly, but explains the frustration the OP had. On the other hand, it's a good life lesson. To be fair, the only real way to answer the question is "learn how to paint". (Or, alternatively, I'd say embrace the paint-by-number aesthetic as its own thing...)

Answer (score 2):

Just found your question from last year. Don't know if you changed your painting. I think you can definitely improve it. I'm not an expert - have done Paint by Numbers, some non-PBN kits (Famous Art Kits), and a couple group painting classes.

I think what you want is to (1) blur the odd PBN shapes, and (2) lighten/mute the colors.

I suggest getting a 3-pack of basic painting brushes, for about $3-4). With a small brush and a light hand, do some tiny brushstrokes of a light color, all around the fur. Switch to another light color. Switch back. You will be layering paint, which looks more realistic. In some places, the brushstrokes will be wavy, because it's fur. Don't try too hard. You're not looking for perfection, which tends to look fake - but impressionism, which ironically, looks more realistic.

I would repaint the nose, so you can make the shine softer. What were they thinking?!

If you want, you could soften the background - but I don't think it's essential.

Put a dot of white symmetrically in each eye when you're done (think Minions) - makes it look more real.

I'm really glad you asked this. I had been avoiding PBN, but now I realize I can improve them as well. Cheers.